# Extracting a 1 dimensional array from a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, arduino

I'm trying to make a program that will read some data into a 2 dimensional array. In order to test the functionality I've made this little example program. The variable is currently declared as a fixed 2 dimensional array and contains some boolean data.

```
boolean runData[4][20] = {
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};
```

Now, I have a function to which I have to pass this data, the function takes a 1 dimensional Boolean array as an argument:

```
void fireLEDs(boolean states[20]){
    ...
}
```

So this means I have to segment this data into 4 single-dimension arrays and pass each of them to the fireLEDs function.

The code I'm trying right now to do this is:

```
for(int b=0;b<4;b++){
    fireLEDs(runData[b][]);
    delayMicroseconds(divDelay);
}
```

However, this doesn't work.

I'm not very good with C, so such a function might not exist at all, but some google-fu says that this should be working.

As a note: I'm using the arduino compiler, but this question has little to do with that I think.

Comment: `However, this doesn't work.` is not a very good problem statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: does `doesn't work` mean a compiler error or wrong output ? `runData[b]` would work as long as function `void fireLEDs(boolean states[20])` would only read 20 elements.Since creation of a 2D array stored everything in memory contigously,meaning if the function reading more than 20 would read elements in next array in the 2D array

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Apologies, but there isn't much of a statement, the program just doesn't compile. The error given is "expected primary-expression before ']' token" on the line that calls the 'fireLEDs' function.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you should change

```
 fireLEDs(runData[b][]);
```

to

```
 fireLEDs(runData[b]);
```

Comment: Hey, this does compile, however this stems into another question. If I wanted to extract a 'column' so to speak from the data, what would I do then?

Comment: @Khurram What do you mean `extract`? There are many ways. Just using `runData[b]` will also do the job.

Comment: Maybe I'm just a bit confused. Anyway the change you suggested does compile, but I'll do some testing and make sure its behaving like I want it to. Thanks

Comment: @Khurram sure, go ahead. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a magic number like 20 in the function then the function should be declared like

```
void fireLEDs( boolean states[], size_t n );
```

To call this function correctly you should write for example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( runData ) / sizeof( *runData ); i++ )
{
    fireLEDs( runData[i], sizeof( runData[i] ) / sizeof( *runData[i] ) );
}
```